# Google slides HTTP requests API's

Tags: google-slides-api, bubble.io

I am a bubble.io developer but ran into a problem I haven't had previously, trying to push data (just creating a new slide) from bubble.io to google slides using the following API:

[https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/[presentationId]:batchUpdate](https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/%5BpresentationId%5D:batchUpdate)

Where presentationId is the name of the file which is added as an extra parameter.

[Snapshot of bubble API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRCd2.png)

I used the following JSON:
[JSON snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA63K.png)

When I "Initialize the call" I get the following error:

[Initilization error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpSyr.png)

Can anyone please assist as my **OAUTH** and **Scopes** are all correct.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think that the error of `Requested entity was not found.` occurs when the value of `presentationId` is an invalid value. But, unfortunately, I do not know your actual situation from your question. I apologize for my poor English skill. In this case, how about confirming the value of `presentationId`, again? Or, how about confirming whether your access token can access the Google Slide of `presentationId`, again? By the way, when I tested your endpoint with a valid value of `presentationId` and access token, no error occurred and I confirmed that a new slide was inserted.

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming that a new slide was inserted, at least I know that is one possible reason for failure that I can cross off my list, appreciate the effort.